# Wait the time of calculation in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use vba run the loop for the data (2010, 2011) (2011, 2012) (2012, 2013)...to create a new workbook one by one.

But here is a problem that, when we enter the parameter `Current:` and `Previous:` we need wait for a while for the calculation of the formulas(It is on the Bloomberg terminal), if we create or copy the data in the sheet immediately, it may be empty or (Data requesting). So how do I solve this problem?

[image]

```
Sub Copy()
  For i = 2015 To 2017
     ThisWorkbook.Activate
     Range("C8") = i
     Range("C9") = i + 1

     Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks.Add
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
     wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VBA test\" & i & ".xlsx"

  Next i
End Sub
```

My questions are

1.How to save as value?

2.In this case, the new book always has a empty `sheet1` and a copied `sheet1(1)` could I only have a copied `sheet1`?

3.How to close the new workbooks when created or don't let them be open(In this case, I have a lot of opened workbooks)

4.How to stay after the syntax `Range("C9") = i + 1` to give the enough time to the calculation by the original workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

2.

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
```

3.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

4.

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))'wait 10 seconds
```

To sum it up:

```
Sub Copy()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2015 To 2017
     ThisWorkbook.Activate
     Range("C8") = i
     Range("C9") = i + 1
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))'wait 10 seconds
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     Set ws = ActiveSheet
     ws.Cells.Copy
     ws.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     ws.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
     wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VBA test\" & i & ".xlsx"
     wb.Close
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I took this parts from my old macro, but should work fine.

I added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True`. Always use it in macros that are doing a lot of changes on your screen (deleting/inserting rows/columns, opening/closing workbooks etc.).

Comment: thanks a lot! why the `ws` is the `sheet1` in `wb`? By the way, if we create a new file, but there is a old file whose name is same as the new file, how to delete the old first then create the new one?

Comment: After executing `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` you will get new workbook with copied sheet and it will become your `ActiveWorkbook` (and `ActiveSheet`). I hope it answers your question. For the second question, please ask it in new topic (after you do some research ;))

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing... Try to write twice `Calculate`, it would slow down the loop and thus it probably would be ok:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5

        Calculate
        Worksheets(i).Copy After:=Worksheets(i + 1)
        Calculate

    Next i

End Sub
```